# Update dynamically python labels color and value memory hungry

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have an interface with hundreds of labels to update - colors and values from strings that came from socket TCP. I found that after a while 20-30 days the program is eating memory GB. So I put this simple piece of code to simulate the same thing and still this simple code is eating memory each second aprox 0.1Mb in activity monitor (mac). Same for mac, linux or windows. I try to track the problem from days now and I cannot figure it why. I put 10 ms on root for accelerate. Originally in 20-30 days my program updating labels from data at 1000ms go very slowly. It does the same thing, updating simple labels using self.after .... As novice in python please understand the quality of the issue.

or there is other alternatives to updates hundreds of labels continuously without memory consumption building up?

```
from Tkinter import *
import datetime

root = Tk()

lab = Label(root)
lab.pack()

def clock():
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("Time: %H:%M:%S") # just for example, could be a variable that is changing rapidly
    lab.config(text=time)
    #lab['text'] = time
    root.after(10, clock) # run and show label updates

# run first time
clock()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you calling the function 100 times per second when the value to display only changes once per second? If there are memory problems, it seems like you ought to be able to reduce it by a couple orders of magnitude.

Comment: The original code was once per second but in 20-30 days the code is using to much memory. But I do not wanted to wait 20 day I have increase the show time and is doing the same, eating memory with this simple code. So I track this problem down to above code, in one night run 500Mb already taken. I want to understand witch part of this code take memory on each loop and how to deal with. I use python 2.7.10, IDE Pycharm and/or IDLE on mac, linux, windows.

Comment: The values shown change once per second its  true, because the variable in this case is time. The question is not the update interval. Why I have memory increase issues over the period of running this code.